# bash -w (is file writable) not returning expected result

Tags: bash, permissions, built-in

I have a file which is switching permissions at will so am attempting to audit it. I built a simple bash script to test if the file is writable using `[ -w $FILE]` but the results are not as expected.

To break this down I'm testing it on the `anaconda-ks.cfg` file in root's home which I ran `chmod 000` on:

```
----------. 1 root root     2222 Apr  6 12:38 anaconda-ks.cfg
```

Obviously not writable. But the output of the following is true:

```
# test -w anaconda-ks.cfg ; echo $?
0
```

Running `test -w` as a standard user produces the expected result. Looking at `stat` on this file returns:

```
  File: ‘anaconda-ks.cfg’
  Size: 2222            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 640843      Links: 1
Access: (0000/----------)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Context: system_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0
...
#
```

If it helps this is in bash v4.2.46

Comment: File permissions only apply to non-root users.

Comment: Also the `.` dot following the permissions indicate there's some security context that is applicable

Comment: @chepner, I do not think this is true. Attempting to edit this file presents me with a 'read-only' message no matter who I am.

Comment: That's the editor making its own check using the same set of permission bits. If you are using `vi`, for example, you can use `:w!` to override the readonly bit.

Comment: @chepner, by some casual internet searches it I am ready to concede that you are correct. If someone can find a source for this it'd make a good answer.